# Wizard control inside an AJAX ModalPopUp control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, linq, web, webforms

The wizard causes postback every time the "next" button is clicked, and therefore makes the entire modal popup go away.

Is there a way to combine these two controls such that the modal popup does not go away until the wizard is complete?

If so can someone provide me with sample code?

Comment: Assuming you're using the Microsoft AJAX framework, could you nest an updatePanel inside the modal panel and put your wizard in there?

Comment: @Tim thank you for replying. But when i put updatePanel inside the modalpopup...I get error?? Could you give me a sample code. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for something else and I found this question unanswered.
 So... if you have not found a solution for it. Try following,

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" >
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server">
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Step1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Step2"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                </WizardSteps>
            </asp:Wizard>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```